# Lib folder in virtualenv - where is the locale.py

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyinstaller

A few versions ago, virtualenv featured a Lib folder where, among the site-packages, libraries were stored. I created a env with Python 3.9 today and noticed, that the Lib folder ist empty, except for the site-packages folder.

Also there used to be the folders "Include" and "tcl" .

What has happened to them? I couldn't find anything in the virtualenv changelog.

Specifically, I'm searching for the locale.py which I need for bundling with pyinstaller.

Both environments were created with `virtualenv env`.

Answer (score 1):

> A few versions ago, virtualenv featured a Lib folder where, among the site-packages, libraries were stored.

I think this was created with the command `virtualenv`…

> I created a env with Python 3.9 today and noticed, that the Lib folder ist empty, except for the site-packages folder.

…and this with the command `python -m venv`. They create slightly different kinds of virtual environments.

> Specifically, I'm searching for the locale.py

I think `venv` (unlike `virtualenv`) left it in the main `Lib/` folder (in the global Python directory).

Comment: Hm, I created both environments with "virtualenv env". venv is a module that is shipped with Python and virtualenv is a standalone module. Your comment encouraged me to research a bit further and it seems it might be worth it to look for a different virtualization. pipenv and venv seem to be officially recommended by PyPA / python.org..

Comment: Well, I prefer `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`.